# Delete a certain number of zeros from right of a string

Tags: python, python-2.7, strip

I'm trying to delete a certain number of zeros from right. For example:

```
"10101000000"
```

I want to remove 4 zeros... And get:

```
"1010100"
```

I tried to do `string.rstrip("0")` or `string.strip("0")` but this removes all the of zeros from right. How can I do that?

The question is not a duplicate because I can't use imports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a known number of zeros you can use slicing:

```
s = "10101000000"
zeros = 4

if s.endswith("0" * zeros):
    s = s[:-zeros]
```

Comment: I need this solution to define the number of zeros. For me, this answer is correct! Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use a regex

```
>>> import re
>>> mystr = "10101000000"
>>> numzeros = 4
>>> mystr = re.sub("0{{{}}}$".format(numzeros), "", mystr)
>>> mystr
'1010100'
```

This will leave the string as is if it doesn't end in four zeros

You could also check and then slice

```
if mystr.endswith("0" * numzeros):
    mystr = mystr[:-numzeros]
```

Comment: I think that he can't use imports

Comment: Yes @FernandoGallegoFernández . But thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`rstrip` deletes all characters from the end that are in passed set of characters. You can delete trailing zeros like this:

```
s = s[:-4] if s[-4:] == "0"*4 else s
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution:

```
number = "10101000000"
def my_rstrip(number, char, count=4):
    for x in range(count):
        if number.endswith(char):
            number = number[0:-1]
        else:
            break
    return number

print my_rstrip(number, '0', 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to split off the last 4 characters from the string by this way:

```
string[:-4]
```

Comment: You want to take off 4 characters from the end of the string, so, you use string[:number of character where you begin to take off characters]

Comment: If you use string[:6] as I rode here, you assume that the string length is allways constant.

Comment: You can use negative indexes instead of using `len` function.

Comment: Why would anyone do `string[:len(string)-4]` instead of just `string[:-4]`? @FernandoGallegoFernández

Comment: It's just another way to do it.I think that shows well how it works the `string[x:y]` method

Comment: Ok, I just updated the answer without the first solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s[:-4]+s[-4:].replace('0000','')
```

Comment: downvote? please comment where does this fail (except when `len(s)<4`)?

Comment: Actually, it's slower than most of other solutions.

Comment: *slow* is not *incorrect* or *invalid*. The only reason I see to downvote this answer is its lack of explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to convert to `str`

```
import re

a = 10101000000

re.sub("0000$","", str(a))
```